# getting The og:url property should be explicitly provided when defining the data-href fb-comments

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to add fb-comments into my html page that is part of the facebook app
like this :

```
data-href="http://ec2-107-22-163-16.compute-1.amazonaws.com/?userid=<?php echo $userId ?><?php echo $userTBID ?> "
```

when i try to render the page im getting this error:

```
Warning: http://ec2-107-22-163-16.compute-1.amazonaws.com/?userid=55700201320 is unreachable.
```

but i do access it from the outside world.

```
now when i click the link , im rederected to the debbuger that tells me this :
Critical Errors That Must Be Fixed
Error Scraping Page:    Bad Response Code

Errors That Must Be Fixed
Missing Required Property:  The og:url property is required, but not present.
Missing Required Property:  The og:type property is required, but not present.
Missing Required Property:  The og:title property is required, but not present.

Open Graph Warnings That Should Be Fixed
Inferred Property:  The og:url property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property:  The og:title property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
```

what is it i just what to be able to add comments widget unique to each user that logedin

**UPDATE:**
i added the og tags but still when i put the url in debug im getting 
Response Code:  403

this is what i added :

```
<head>
<title>encomia</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="MyAppName"/>
        <meta property="og:url" content="http://ec2-107-22-163-16.compute-1.amazonaws.com/?userid=<?php echo $userId ?><?php echo $userTBID ?>" />
</head>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I go to:

http://ec2-107-22-163-16.compute-1.amazonaws.com/?userid=55700201320

I get back a 403 forbidden error message.

I'll bet Facebook is seeing this as well and cannot properly lint the url.  Accroding to the linter, it says

> Error Scraping Page:  Bad Response Code

So make sure you send back a 200 code with the real content rather than a 403.

Comment: i added the og tags but still i cant do the fb comments right

Comment: Correct, because of the 403 error code your server is sending.

Answer (score 0):

Its asking you to insert some `og:tags` onto your page.  The `og:tags` help [Open Graph Protocol](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) to see information about your site so that it can display it correctly on facebook.

You can read about the tags and their values at [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/).